# How to set derby.database.classpath to run Java DB Embedded?

Tags: database, classpath, derby, embedded-database, javadb

I have been searching documents about this similar problem all day long, but it seems I can't find the answer. I easily found a database in a server client mode (org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver), but I was confused about resulting database in embedded mode (org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver).

Everything seems alright, and the connection to the database is a success, but it always gives me this error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'APP.TABELJEMBATAN' does
>   not exist.
>
> ```
> http://i1263.photobucket.com/albums/ii633/lindafitriani/javadb4.jpg
> ```

My database exists, see below:

> ```
> http://i1263.photobucket.com/albums/ii633/lindafitriani/javadb1.jpg
> http://i1263.photobucket.com/albums/ii633/lindafitriani/javadb2.jpg
> ```

Here is the content of my derby.log file:

> 2012-06-30 18:08:34.170 GMT:  Booting Derby version The Apache
>   Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.5.3.0 - (802917): instance
>   a816c00e-0138-3e94-78a3-000000b35a08 on database directory
>   C:\Users\Linda Fitriani\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Jembatan\Jembatan2
>
> Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
>
> ```
> http://i1263.photobucket.com/albums/ii633/lindafitriani/javadb3.jpg
> ```

The database location is right (on my working directory) but the derby.database.classpath was empty.... Anyone know how to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
package jembatan;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
/**
 *
 * @author Linda Fitriani
 */
public class DBConnect {
        private static Connection conn;
    private static String url = "jdbc:derby:Jembatan2;create=true;";
    private static String user = "APP";
    private static String pass = "linda";

    public static Connection connect() throws SQLException{
        try{
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
            System.err.println("Error: ClassNotFoundException"+cnfe.getMessage());
        }catch(InstantiationException ie){
            System.err.println("Error:InstantiationException"+ie.getMessage());
        }catch(IllegalAccessException iae){
            System.err.println("Error:IllegalAccessException"+iae.getMessage());
        }

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
        return conn;
    }
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        if(conn !=null && !conn.isClosed())
            return conn;
        connect();
        return conn;

    }
}


private void buildData(){

          Connection c ;
          data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
          try{
              c = DBConnect.connect();
            //SQL FOR SELECTING ALL OF APP.TABELJEMBATAN
            String SQL = "select * from APP.TABELJEMBATAN";
            //ResultSet
            ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

            /**********************************
             * TABLE COLUMN ADDED DYNAMICALLY *
             **********************************/

            for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
                final int j = i;                
                TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
                col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){                    
                    public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {                                                                                              
                        return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());                        
                    }                    
                });

                tableview.getColumns().addAll(col); 
                col.setMinWidth(200);
                System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");
            }

            /********************************
             * Data added to ObservableList *
             ********************************/
            while(rs.next()){
                //Iterate Row
                ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                    //Iterate Column
                    row.add(rs.getString(i));
                }
                System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );
                data.add(row);

            }

            //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView
            tableview.setItems(data);
          }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
              System.out.println("Error on Building Data");             
          }

      }
```

Comment: anybody want to answer how to set derby classpath? any help would be great appreciate

Answer (score 2):

i found the solution...

embedded mode creates database on neatbeans install directory..
so, i just pointing to

```
"jdbc:derby:C:/Users/Linda Fitriani/.netbeans/7.1/derby/databaseJembatan;create=false;"
```

that's why the application doesn't find the database, databases are in the netbeans install directory..

Answer (score 1):

just be sure that you add create=true within the database connection URL
and make sure that url refer to directory where the db located 
Specifies the classpath that Derby should use when searching for jar files in a database
make sure that you add DerbyClient.jar to your project libraries

and next time you run the application you will note that you should not start server again
and when you copy jar files to another location be sure that (lib) directory with it

i hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into a different problem (cannot show tables in hive) but with SAME log message after installing hive and derby

I finally realized that the ownership issue (hduser should be granted as owner of the hive folders...).e